# Mixed effect zero inflated negative binomial model: "the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite"

Tags: r, mixed-model, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation, glmmadaptive

I am having trouble fitting a mixed effect zero inflated negative binomial model to my data using the **GLMMadaptive** package:

```
mixed_model(abun ~ TREATMENT + Size + R , random = ~1 | PLOT.TR,
              data = abunIP, family = zi.negative.binomial(), 
              zi_fixed = ~grass.cut)
```

returns: `Error in chol.default(X[[i]], ...) : the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite` I can't find anything about this particular error message for these models.

My data has 978 rows. The resonse `abun` is count data (flowers). `TREATMENT` and `PLOT.TR` are factors indicating plot type and a unique plot ID, respectively. `Size`, and `R` are continuous variables. `grass.cut` indicates whether weeding occurred before a survey, which could reduce the `abun` value, often to 0, which is why I am trying to use a zero-inflated model.

**UPDATE**

Following Dimitris' answer below, I found that the combination of solutions 1 and 2 worked for me, though I made the change `list(betas = rep(0,7))` because `TREATMENT` is a factor with 5 levels.

By only adding the `initial_values` argument, I got the error message

```
Error in mixed_fit(y, X, Z, X_zi, Z_zi, id, offset, offset_zi, family,  : 
  A large coefficient value has been detected during the optimization.
 Please re-scale you covariates. Alternatively, this may due to a
 divergence of the optimization algorithm, indicating that an overly
 complex model is fitted to the data. For example, this could be
 caused when including random-effects terms (e.g., in the
 zero-inflated part) that you do not need. Otherwise, adjust the
 'max_coef_value' control argument.
```

However, specifying `iter_EM = 0` in addition resulted in no error messages.

I have a follow-up question: Conceptually, what is `iter_EM = 0` doing, and is it addressing the previous error message I get by specifying `initial_values` appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to see what may be causing the problem without a reproducible example, but some things to check are:

1. Change initial values for the fixed effects coefficients using the `initial_values` argument of `mixed_model()`, e.g.,

   ```
   mixed_model(abun ~ TREATMENT + Size + R , random = ~ 1 | PLOT.TR,
               data = abunIP, family = zi.negative.binomial(), 
               zi_fixed = ~ grass.cut,
               initial_values = list(betas = rep(0, 3)))
   ```

   potentially you could also change the initial value for the variance of the random intercepts using `initial_values = list(betas = rep(0, 3))`.
2. You could try setting the number of EM iterations to zero using `mixed_model(..., iter_EM = 0)` to only use the quasi-Newton part of the optimization procedure.
3. If you have a (complete) separation issue, you could try invoking the `penalized` argument of `mixed_model()` that will place a Student's t penalty for the fixed effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my follow up question is: conceptually, what is `iter_EM = 0` doing, and is it addressing the error message I get by specifying `initial_values` appropriately?

Comment: Check the vignette about the optimization procedure in **GLMMadaptive**: https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Optimization.html ; `iter_EM` sets the number of EM iterations. When you set it to zero it means that you're only using the quasi-Newton algorithm.